# Obtaining Feature Id in Angular Google Maps Data Layer LayerClick Event

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-google-maps

I have successfully added a GeoJSON file to the data layer of an [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) application, and would like to be able to access the feature's properties and ID when the user clicks on one of the polygons drawn on that layer. However, I am receiving an error when attempting to access the `feature` property of the `layerClick` arguments.

Here is a short example summarizing the problem:

**home.component.html:**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
  <agm-data-layer [geoJson]="geoJson" [style]="styleFunc" (layerClick)="onClick($event)"></agm-data-layer>
</agm-map>
```

**home.component.ts**:

```
export class HomeComponent {
    latitude: number = 5;
    longitude: number = 5;
    zoom: number = 4;
    geoJson = JSON.parse(`
    {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": 10,
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 10.0], [10.0, 10.0], [10.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]]
          },
          "properties": {
            "name": "Alpha",
            "color": "#FF0000"
          }
        }, {
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": 20,
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[11.0, 11.0], [11.0, 20.0], [20.0, 20.0], [20.0, 11.0], [11.0, 11.0]]]
          },
          "properties": {
            "name": "Bravo",
            "color": "#0000FF"
          }
        }]
    }`);

    styleFunc(feature: any): any {
        return ({
            clickable: true,
            fillColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
    }

    onClick(clickEvent: DataMouseEvent): void {
        console.log('Click Event Detected');
        console.log(clickEvent.latLng.toString());
        console.log(clickEvent.feature.id);
        console.log(clickEvent.feature.properties.name);
    }
```

The map is displaying and coloring the polygons as expected:

[image: Map Working Correctly]

However, I receive the following error when clicking on one of the shaded regions (example below is for red region):

[image: Error Message]

I am using `@agm/core` version `"~1.0.0-beta.7"` and Angular 8.2, running in an ASP.Net Core 3.0 application.

**UPDATED 10/29/19**

Per itminus' question below, I attempted the following modificaiton:

```
    onClick(clickEvent: DataMouseEvent): void {
        console.log('Click Event Detected');
        console.log(clickEvent.latLng.toString());
        console.log(clickEvent.feature.getId());
        console.log(clickEvent.feature.getProperty('name'));
    }
```

After making these changes, IntelliSense reported an error on both getId() and getProperty(), saying that those properties do not exist. The project built with no errors, but I received a 404 error at startup, and the following error in the output window:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: ERROR in
>   src/app/home/home.component.ts(51,40): error TS2339: Property 'getId'
>   does not exist on type 'Feature'.
>   src/app/home/home.component.ts(52,40): error TS2339: Property
>   'getProperty' does not exist on type 'Feature'.

Comment: I don't know how ASP ties into this, but I was able to run your code and get an id with `getId`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getId()` + `getProperty('propName')` functions to get the id & props:

```js
onClick(clickEvent): void {
    console.log('Click Event Detected');
    console.log(clickEvent);
    console.log(clickEvent.latLng.toString());
    console.log(clickEvent.feature);

    console.log(clickEvent.feature.getId());
    clickEvent.feature.forEachProperty(p =>{
      console.log(p);
    });
    console.log(clickEvent.feature.getProperty("name"));
    console.log(clickEvent.feature.getProperty("color"));
}
```

See [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#declarative_style_rules):

```
var ascii = feature.getProperty('ascii');
```

Comment: See my updated question above. Neither getId() nor getProperty() exist on the Feature interface as implemented by agm. Reviewing the agm code, it appears that they may have incorrectly implemented Feature as FeatureOptions, and left out several important methods.

Comment: @BrettWolfington I just searched the source code of AGM, but I didn't find any type declaration for `getId()`/`getProperty()` method (which come from Google Map it self).  I'm not sure whether it is a bug or not. Whatever, as a quick fix, you could  remove the type annotation for  `clickEvent` in `onClick(clickEvent: DataMouseEvent)`, i.e., change it to `onClick(clickEvent): void` or `onClick(clickEvent: any): void`.

Comment: @itminus it is a bug in our typing, however will not affect runtime. Since we are soon  switching from our types to @types/googlemaps, it's irrelevent.
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bdb0d39904820c5f4729d12cb5f5223139231c2f/types/googlemaps/index.d.ts#L493

Comment: @f.khantsis Thanks for your information :) You're awesome